# Flutter - How test drawer in widgets test?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, flutter-test

I'm testing my Flutter app. I have a widget drawer. I am doing a test for this widget. I need to open the box and click on the items. I use this code:

```
final  drawer = find.byTooltip('Open navigation menu');
expect(drawer, findsWidgets);
tester.tap(drawer) ;
```

It is work. But I don't know how finds items in my drawer anb tap to them.
This is code for drawer:

```
    drawer: Drawer(
    key: Key("Drawer"),
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
         drawerItem(context, 'Login', Icons.account_circle, 'login'),
         drawerItem(context, 'Users', Icons.person, 'users'),
         drawerItem(context, 'Log Out', Icons.exit_to_app, 'logout')
      ],
    ),
  )

  .....

  ListTile drawerItem(BuildContext context, String title, IconData icon,
  [String route]) {
  return new ListTile(
  key: Key(title),
  title: Text(title),
  leading: Icon(icon)
     );
```

How do I click on these items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a finder by type, that should give your an array of all the items of an specific type, then just access the items by index like this. `find.byType(ListTile).at(index);`

Comment: did you try this? `tester.tap(find.byType(ListTile).first);`